# Problems with ranges in Excel Interop

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I'm writing a program in C# that accesses the Excel Interop interface to create a spreadsheet. My program creates a worksheet, then enters some text into the first row.  I want to set the font to bold for the first row, as a title, but things aren't working as expected.

First I create a range object for the row, then I set the BOLD attribute

```
Range rng1 = ws.Rows[1];
rng1.Style.Font.Bold = true;
```

This works OK and afterwards I have a bold header line.  However, I noticed that the rest of the spreadsheet was getting set to bold also.  So I added some code to turn it OFF but it didn't work as expected.  The code looks like this:

```
Range rng2 = ws.Rows[rownum];
rng2.Style.Font.Bold = false;
```

The "rownum" variable starts at 2 and increments through 12.  It's never set to 1.  So this should be creating a second range object that has zero overlap with the first one.  Yet for some reason, this turns off the bold attribute for everything.

It seems like the entire spreadsheet is affected by turning BOLD on or off. Oh, and I can do these steps in any order.

Any ideas what's going on and how to fix it?

Comment: when you assign or set the bold for cells / rows you need to specify which cells to start from and end .. also it appears you are not posting enough code can you post all relevant code as it pertains to your current issue

Comment: post a minimum and complete example plz

Comment: This is very strange and almost hints that Excel might be inheriting the format of the cells above.  I've seen this within a row but never across columns, so that's probably unlikely.  I do agree with the previous two comments, though, in that if you post more code -- enough for an outsider to repeat the issue, it would go a long way

Comment: All the relevant code was already included.  I discovered the problem was fixed by accessing "rng2.Font.Bold" instead of "rng2.Style.Font.Bold"

Comment: @MikeFulton so My answer did helped you? The one above

Comment: @joemartin94 - Sorry, no it didn't.  I ended up figuring out a solution on my own as indicated in the comment right above yours.